# Inserting one document to another Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

I am dealing with Word VSTO add-in. I wrote a code that inserts one document to another. I have two different approaches.

1) `Copy`/`Paste`

```
var app = new Word.Application();
            var MyDoc = app.Documents.Add(@"C:\install\CSharp\Plank.dotm");
            MyDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.WholeStory();
            MyDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.CopyFormat();
            Word.Document doc = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument;
            doc.Activate();
            doc.ActiveWindow.Selection.PasteFormat();
```

2) `InsertFile()`

```
var app = new Word.Application();

            var MyDoc = app.Documents.Add(@"C:\install\CSharp\Plank.dotm");
            Word.Document doc = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument;
            doc.Activate();
                       //Taking margins
            float TopMargin = MyDoc.PageSetup.TopMargin;
            float RightMargin = MyDoc.PageSetup.RightMargin;
            float LeftMargin = MyDoc.PageSetup.LeftMargin;
            Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection.InsertFile(@"C:\\install\CSharp\Plank.dotm", Link: false, Attachment: false);
```

At the first approach the line `PasteFormat()` is not working, telling me that text properties were not copied. (If I use just `Copy()` and `Paste()` it works.) Even if I paste manually I get what I want.

The second approach works, but it doesn't take text formatting. So I get the text in some other format and size which differs from the original.

QUESTION is: How can I preserve original font formats? I tried to insert a file in Word manually. And I can't get the original text formatting there either. Maybe it is a wrong approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out with the `Copy()` / `Paste()` solution. I need to copy like this:

```
MyDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.Copy();
doc.ActiveWindow.Selection.PasteAndFormat(Word.WdRecoveryType.wdFormatOriginalFormatting);
```

Then it preserves the styles. But sometimes, if the document has tables, it copies them to the next page, which is strange. The `InsertFile()` method is not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

PasteFormat will paste only format, not the contents and should be used after CopyFormat method. PasteAndFormat method should be used to paste contents with or without format as defined with WdRecoveryType constant. Here you should be using:

doc.ActiveWindow.Selection.PasteAndFormat(Word.WdRecoveryType.wdFormatOriginalFormatting);

For further info read [PasteAndFormat method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.selection.pasteandformat) and [WdRecoveryType constant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wdrecoverytype)

Answer (score 0):

Some background information on the behavior: By default and by design Word will use the same ***style*** definitions as defined in the *target* document so that content coming in is merged "seamlessly" (from a formatting perspective). If the incoming content has the same style name(s) applied as already present in the target document, the formatting of the incoming content will change.

As shown in an answer, the `PasteAndFormat` with the parameter `Word.WdRecoveryType.wdFormatOriginalFormatting` method when using the Windows Clipboard will override the default behavior and retain the original formatting.

Working via the Clipboard is not always desired or ideal, however. There is another way, which is to change the style name(s) in the source document so that they're different than in the target document. This approach will work if styles have been used *consistently* in the source document. (Formatting applied manually may still be lost, however.)

The following code snippet illustrates the approach for paragraph styles. It creates a new style based on the styles used in the document - the new style is an exact duplicate except for the name. A Find/Replace is then performed to replace all instances of the style with the new style. Now the content can be inserted into another document and the formatting is maintained.

```
    Word.Document doc = wdApp.ActiveDocument;
    Word.Style sOld = null;
    Word.Style sCopy = null;
    Word.Find f = doc.Content.Find;

    //Select Normal text, otherwise Normal will take on character formatting of current selected text
    Word.Selection sel = wdApp.Selection;
    sel.Find.set_Style(Word.WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleNormal);
    sel.Find.Execute("", Type.Missing,
      Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, true, Word.WdFindWrap.wdFindStop,
      true, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

    foreach (Word.Style s in doc.Styles)
    {
        if ((s.InUse) && (s.Type == Word.WdStyleType.wdStyleTypeParagraph) && 
            (!s.NameLocal.Contains(" Copy")))
        {
            sOld = s;
            sCopy = doc.Styles.Add(sOld.NameLocal + " Copy", sOld.Type);
            sCopy.set_BaseStyle(sOld);
            f.set_Style(sOld);
            f.Replacement.set_Style(sCopy);
            f.Execute("", Type.Missing, 
            Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, true, Word.WdFindWrap.wdFindStop, 
            true, "", Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
        }
    }
```